# How to create Generic method for Gson marshal and unmarshal?

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I am new to Generics.

I tried to create generic Gson marshal (i.e., gson.toJson()) and unmarshal (i.e., gson.fromJson())methods.

```
public class Message {
    private MessageBody messageBody;
    ....
}
public class MessageBody {
    private List<BodyParam> bodyParams;
}
public class MessageBodyParam {
    private String name;        
    private Object value;
}

public class JsonUtil {

    //This is not working
    public static <T> String marshal(Object object, Class<T> jtype) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Type type = new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType();
        return gson.toJson(object, type);
    }

    //this is working as expected
    public static <T> T unmarshal(String jsonStr, Class<T> jtype) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonStr, type);
    }
}
```

I am calling these methods as following:

```
//Message is my class
String jsonMessage = JsonUtil.marshal(message, Message.class);
Message message = JsonUtil.unmarshal(message, Message.class);
```

how to receive the class type in JsonUtil.marshal() and return the String object ?

Please help me to resolve this. 
Thanks.

Comment: `new TypeToken<T>() {}` cannot actually work.  You need to use `jtype`.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, I tried with jtype but it is giving "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to ...." because my Message.class having some collection property as well. When I searched in SO for that. I came to know about  TypeToken

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding what `TypeToken` does.

Comment: @SLaks I have updated the question with Message.class and its sub classes. Please let me know how to resolve the exception "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to ...."  without using TypeToken.  Thanks

Comment: What is the full exception message & stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks 
When I tried to cast the MessageBodyParam->"Object value" to "Log" . I got the following exception:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.*.*.Log
 at *****.*Listener.receiveMessage(ServiceMessageListener.java:61) ~[classes/:?]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]

Comment: That's because Gson has no way of knowing that it should create a `Log` object.  You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks Is there any way to resolve that ? Or any workaround to achieve ?

Comment: Don't use `Object`, or write a converter to tell Gson how to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

its too late but this solution is working for me to create a generic class for gson :

```
public class JSONConversion<T>{

    private  T t;


    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public void setT(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public String ObjectToString(){

        Gson gson=new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(t);

    }
    public T StringToObject(String jsonString ,Class<T> tt){
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, tt);
    }

}
```

you can use this generic gson class like this:

```
LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
JSONConversion<LoginResponse> jsonConversion=new JSONConversion<>();
jsonConversion.setT(loginResponse);
String createdJson=jsonConversion.ObjectToString());
Log.d("toJson",createdJson);            
LoginResponse convertedObject=jsonConversion.StringToObject(createdJson,LoginResponse.class);
```